# How to append div content in reverse order with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have ajax call which gets results from database. But when I append div with html the order of content is reversed. How can I re-reverse it to set last item as a first. I don't want to order content in SQL. Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

```
$.each(data.idUser.matches, function(index, element) {
$('.myDiv').append('<div>...SOME LONG HTML CONTENT'</div')
```

Comment: `data.idUser.matches.reverse(),....`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add at the top of a container rather than at the bottom of it.

Alternately, of course, just reverse the array before looping through it. Arrays have a built-in `reverse` method.

Or loop through it backward with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.prepend()` here.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    $('.myDiv').prepend('<div>...SOME LONG HTML CONTENT - ' + index + '</div>');
});
```

Check out the fiddle to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xwmcnfu/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Jquery.reverse() function, here's a fiddle with the example.

```
<ul class="ioi">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
```

```
var i = 0;

$($("li").get().reverse()).each(function() {
  $( this ).html(i);
  i++;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86LLftwe